# Accessing AWS Pinpoint in Lambda from Behind VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-vpc, aws-pinpoint

My goal is to send a SMS message through AWS Pinpoint using NodeJS and the AWS Pinpoint Gateway from behind a VPC. The code I am using works well on my local machine and in SAM where there are no VPC restrictions. I added a SNS and SMS VPC endpoint with security groups that give me access to each service individually. I can send an SMS using the aws-sdk SNS service.

I cannot seem to get Lambda to use pinpoint to send an SMS message. Is this possible? I cannot seem to find ports for the Pinpoint service? Is it possible to avoid exposing internet access to the VPN to send messages through AWS Pinpoint?

Role: Assigned All Pinpoint roles, SMS and SNS permissions for testing.

Message Configuration:

```
    const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    AWS.config.update({region: process.env.SMS_REGION});
    const PINPOINT = new AWS.Pinpoint({apiVersion: '2016-12-01'}); 
    const PINPOINT_APP_ID = process.env.PINPOINT_APP_ID;
    const params = {
    ApplicationId: PINPOINT_APP_ID,
    MessageRequest: {
     Addresses: {
       [number]: {
         ChannelType: 'SMS'
       }
     },
     MessageConfiguration: {
       SMSMessage: {
           Body: message,
           OriginationNumber: origination_number,
           SenderId: "senderId",
           MessageType: process.env.SMS_MESSAGE_TYPE
       }
     }
    }
};
await PINPOINT.sendMessages(params, (err, data) => {});
```

Region: us-west-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **no VPC interface endpoints** for AWS Pinpoint, as shown in this AWS [list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/integrated-services-vpce-list.html). Therefore, you need to go through internet to access the service.

For your lambda, you have to place it in **private subnet** with NAT gateway in public subnet. Thanks to the NAT, your lambda function will be able to access pinpoint service.

The alternative would be to use **private API gateway** which integrates with other lambda as a proxy. Not ideal solution, but at the end of the day you have to go through internet, one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Pinpoint endpoint is now available: com.amazonaws.region.pinpoint-sms-voice-v2 and the updated list is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html).